# How to kill process on Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: c#, c++, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6

I use [ProcessCE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36841/Compact-Framework-Process-class-that-supports-full).

It works fine on Windows mobile 6.1. 
But on Windows Mobile 6.5 -> When I kill with Terranova.API TerminateProcess throws exception with error 6 = ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE.

```
internal static void KillProcess(IntPtr pid)
    {

        IntPtr process_handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, false, (int)pid);

        if (process_handle == (IntPtr)INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "OpenProcess failed.");

        try
        {
            bool result = TerminateProcess(process_handle, 0);

            if (result == false)
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "TerminateProcess failed."); //THROW EXCEPTION on Windows Mobile 6.5

        }
        finally
        {
            CloseHandle(process_handle);
        }
    }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The code is incorrectly checking `OpenProcess()` for failure.  The documentation for [OpenProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms886766.aspx) states the return value when the function fails is `NULL`. In C, `NULL` is just a macro that expands to `0`, so in C# you should use `IntPtr.Zero` in place of `NULL` when referencing Win32 API.

If a process did indeed have the handle of `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` then this code would throw an exception when there was no error condition.

Win32 API uses `HANDLE` inconsistently. In some cases the function returns `NULL` on failure, in most cases the function returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` on error.  This is one of the cases where the function returns `NULL` rather than `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` to indicate failure.

```
if (process_handle == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "OpenProcess failed.");
```

Answer (score 1):

One reason why the HANDLE returned from OpenProcess is invalid might be that the fdwAccess parameter is not supported in WM6.5 and [should be set to 0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909175.aspx).

Other than that, check the return value for NULL (not INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE), and verify that the pid is valid.